# Set Touch-Virtual-Keyboard Layout/size in WPF Applications (Windows 11) using xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, touch-event

I am developing an application in WPF (Windows 11) that can used by Touch-Devices. In XAML the input scope can be set, thus defining the type of virtual touch keyboard that is automatically opened when the user focus a TextBox (for example, the number-only keyboard):

```
<TextBox InputScope="Number"/>
```

However in Windows 11, the Touch-keyboard size can also be changed by the user (In: Settings > Keyboard Layout > Default/Small/Split/Traditional).

Can I using XAML or C#, define in my WPF-APP the Touch-Keyboard size that is automatically opened (thus avoiding the user to constantly change it)?